# boost::thread without all of boost?

Tags: c++, boost

is there a way to use boost's threading capabilities without the entire boost library? What are the bare minimum h and cpp files needed for this?

Thanks

Comment: I just want cross platform threading

Comment: it will be hard to separate dependencies, what are you objections to having distribution in entirety?

Comment: Is your code actually going to be cross-platform?  We have a Windows-only app where for whatever reason the previous dev pulled in boost SOLELY for thread, mutex, and scoped_lock classes.  It drives me crazy because all other code uses Win32/ATL/MFC and the semantics of using boost are quite different.  Nothing against libraries like boost, but I would ask that you make sure you need it before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread.html

According to the above you need at least

`#include <boost/thread.hpp>`

Comment: This pulls in lots of other headers throughout boost though

Comment: @madrill -- most of boost is header only, and many parts are templates or macros that have no impact on object file size as long as you don't use them. Even if you do pull in more, the linker will discard pieces you don't use when creating an executable (assuming you are doing static linking, which as far as I can tell is typical with boost).

Comment: @John - yes, I appreciate that, but the OP ask for the bare minimum of .h and .cpp files required.  Besides, the thread library is one of the ones that must be built.

Comment: @mandrill -- I realize that the macros/templates are a moot point since the compiler creates them as needed, but regardless, the linker should exclude objects it does not need. While that may not answer the question, it does partially address the issue. Essentially, compiling the thread part of the library and linking against it will only include the parts that are absolutely required for boost::threads.

Comment: I agree that the linker will only include what it needs, but one major reason you may not want the entire boost source is that it's huge (95Mb zipped) and so that may not be desirable depending on your version control policies. We only check in the parts of boost that we need (using bcp to extract). No sense in checking out lots of source you don't need, especially on a slow connection.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the boost [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) tool which will copy only the parts of boost which are required for any of the libraries of your choice.

Comment: @John: Idan K fixed the link :)

Comment: Thanks -- the boost site was quite unresponsive yesterday so it was difficult to tell whether the link was correct.

Comment: It's ok -- from what I could tell, half the internet was unresponsive yesterday. Maybe it was just my cable co, but I figured when the boost site did respond with a 404 I'd help out. The link works now, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a small library that was created for just this purpose: [TinyThread++](http://tinythread.sourceforge.net)

It gives you (sort of) a subset of the upcoming C++0x standard threading API, in just one .h file and one .cpp file (no complicated build, no dependencies). And, it's very portable (and open source, of course).

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Soon you will have std::thread as a standardized version

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-thread

If you have access to C++0x, your favorite compiler may already have some of these things implemented like gcc 4.5+